# Smoke effect with JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have visited a website with a beautiful smoke effect in background ([www.steaw-webdesign.com](http://www.steaw-webdesign.com)). I don't succeed to identify technology behind this effect even if I think about Javascript and JQuery. The effect is applied to a div.

I would like to do something similar but I don't know how, any tutorial or advise?

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: I am thinking it is some background video in loop.

Comment: Just a background video using http://www.steaw-webdesign.com/wp-content/themes/steaw/videos/video_bg.mp4

Answer (score 1):

They are using HTML5 video element

simply go to div with **id="video"** (below `<footer>` tag)

`<div id="video"><img/>` **`<video>`**

you will find `<video>` element with src file

> `<video id="jp_video_0" preload="auto" style="width: 1263px; height: auto;" src="/wp-content/themes/steaw/videos/video_bg.mp4"></video>`